# Unable to autoload constant A, expected <path> to define it rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd searched internet on this problem, and the answers say that the most common things are:

1. Rails naming conventions are begin violated. For example: filename is hello_world.rb and the classname is Hello_World instead of HelloWorld.
2. In config.autoload_paths in application.rb there is no path required.

None of these cases are mine: I got file under /lib/admin_analytics.rb and module name AdminAnalytics. Also I have config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib) in application.rb.

But in development mode, when I change the code and refresh the page (making request) the

> Unable to autoload constant AdminAnalytics, expected /lib/admin_analytics.rb to define it.

error comes. How to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Ruby version 2.6.0
Rails is 5.2.5

The beginning of the module

```rb
module AdminAnalytics

  def self.compute_numbers(options = {})
    require 'admin/compute_numbers'
    # ComputeNumbers.debug = true
    ComputeNumbers.send(options[:method], options)
  end
```

Comment: What's the code in that file? At least, the start of the file, where the name is defined.

Comment: the start is : module AdminAnalytics, and then function definitions

Comment: Do you `require` your module where you're calling it? Or is the error raised before you try to use it at all?

Comment: i dont require it, as I said the error is raised when I change the application code and refresh the page (making request)

Comment: When you say "making request", what do you mean - calling the module? Try requiring the module in the controller where you process the request.

Comment: i mean simple page reloading, simple GET

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question, otherwise we can't easily answer. See how many comments it took to get to this point? If you give us the code instead of trying to describe it in general terms, everything is a lot easier.